# Trying to read ABS.gov Weekly rent data by landlord using readSDMX package

Tags: r, dataframe

## Loading R packages

```
library(rsdmx)
library(tidyverse)
```

## Loading ABS URL

```
dsdUrl<- "http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/ABS_CENSUS2011_B34_LGA"
```

## Use readSDMX  packages to read dsdurl data

```
dsd<- readSDMX(dsdUrl)
```

## Use slot function to read code list

```
cls<- slot(dsd, "codelists")
```

```
codelists<- sapply(slot(cls,"codelists"), function(x) slot(x, "id"))
```

## Use dataframe to create a new data set

```
codelist <- as.data.frame(slot(dsd, "codelists"), codelistId = "CL_ABS_CENSUS2011_B34_LGA_REGION")
```

```
concepts <- as.data.frame(slot(dsd, "concepts"))
```

Comment: Please clarify which is your problem and how we can help you.

Comment: Hi Marc. I am new in the programming and currently trying to collect ABS data using readSDMX method. There, i have found few layer in the table and  find it hard to read the information that i needed.